# How do I create a simple star rating with span or ul li using CSS and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I found an example of star rating with `input` of `type="radio"`.

It's fantastic, but I'd like something simpler. Instead of `input` of `type="radio"`, use star rating with `<span>` [example in demonstration (demo)](https://css-tricks.com/examples/StarRating/).

Of the following code

```css
.holder {
  height: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


/*    Styles hover mouse stars.       */

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* Show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* Hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* Hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* Hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* Lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="" es>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- FontAwsome Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('submit', '#frm-rating', function() {
        //Get form data.
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        //Ajax
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'rating.php',
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
            $("#result-rating").html(data);
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="frm-rating" method="POST">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="left">
        <fieldset class="rating">
          <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Excellent - 5 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="very good - 4.5 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="All right - 4 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="All right - 3.5 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Regular - 3 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Regulate the evil - 2.5 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="wrong - 2 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Very bad - 1.5 stars"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Painful - 1 star"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Waste of time - 0.5 stars"></label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="opinion" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>

    <!-- We use the user's session to get their ID in value -->
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="1" />

    <button type="submit">Submit Review</button>
  </form>

  <div id="result-rating">
    <!-- Respuesta Ajax. -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I create stars of the same characteristics in this code using only CSS and jQuery without using frameworks as Bootstrap or others?

```
<div id="rating" class="rating">
  <span class="stars"></span>
  <span class="stars"></span>
  <span class="stars"></span>
  <span class="stars"></span>
  <span class="stars"></span>
</div>
```

Or this code:

```
<ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon half">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul>
```

And by means of jQuery, get the selected values and send them to the database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', '#frm-rating', function() {
    //Obtenemos datos form.
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    //Ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'rating.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#result-rating").html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

The goal is to have simpler code optimized.

**Example:**

```css
.star-icon {
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.star-icon:before{
    content: '\2605';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.star-icon.full:before {
    color: #fde16d;
    content: '\2605';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.star-icon.half:before {
    color: #fde16d;
    content: '\2605';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: ltr;
}

.star-icon.half:after {
    content: '\2605';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.star-rating > li:hover,
.star-rating > li:hover ~li:before,
.star-rating > li:hover ~li:after
{
    width: 100%;
    color: #fde16d;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon half">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul>
```

Now to know what rating the user has chosen through PHP and jQuery.

Something more dynamic.

```
<?php
    function calculate_stars($max, $rating){
        $full_stars=floor($rating);
        $half_stars = ceil($rating-$full_stars);
        $gray_stars = $max-($full_stars + $half_stars);
        return array ($full_stars, $half_stars, $gray_stars);
    }

    function display_star($rating){
        $output="";
        $number_stars = calculate_stars(5,$rating);
        $full = $number_stars[0];
        $half = $number_stars[1];
        $gray = $number_stars[2];
        $output ='<ul class="star-rating">';
        if($gray)
            for ($i=0;$i<$gray;$i++)
            {
                $output .= '<li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>';
            }

        if($half){
            $output .= '<li class="star-icon half">&#9734;</li>';
        }

        if($full){
            for($i=0; $i<$full;$i++)
            {
                $output .= '<li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>';
            }
        }

        $output .='</ul>';
        return $output;
    }

    echo display_star(4.3);

    exit;
?>
```

[Source](https://www.udemy.com/star-rating-script-with-php-mysql-and-javascript/) observe the first 3 videos explaining the theme.

I do not want to use JavaScript; I want it in jQuery.

Comment: Why would you *want* to swap the `<input>` elements with `<span>`? The whole *point* of them using `<input>` elements was so that they could submit the data through a form. Without an `<input>`, how will you know what rating the user has chosen?

Comment: without which frameworks ? jQuery ? in this case jQuery just do AJAX POST instead of classical POST which cause page reload... with span's you have to use javascript and somehow set POST 'rating' on your own

Comment: @ObsidianAge I updated the question, I hope that with the new details found there is a chance of doing what is desired.

Comment: @Kazz I updated the question, I hope that with the new details found there is a chance of doing what is desired.

Comment: Only use blockquotes for actual quotes and use bold sparingly for emphasis, not to attract attention, so please remove it. This in regards to: `I do not want to use javascript I want it in jquery.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML markup:

```
<ul class="c-rating">
    <li class="c-rating__item rating is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="1"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="2"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="3"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="4"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="5"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="6"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" class="rank" />
```

I have created a custom jQuery plugin for this functionality where you need to pass `childClass` for child selector and `inputClass` for input tag selector.

```
var activeClassCount = 1;
$.fn.customStarRatings = function(obj) {
    var wrapper = this;
    var stars = obj.childClass;
    var input = obj.inputClass;
    $(wrapper).hover(function() {
        activeClassCount = $(this).find('.rating').index() + 1;
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find(stars).slice(1, activeClassCount).addClass('is-active');
        $this.find(stars).slice(activeClassCount, 10).not('.rating').removeClass('is-active');
        // console.log($this.find(stars).slice(activeClassCount, 4).not('.rating'))
    });
    $(stars).hover(function() {
        $(this).prevAll(stars).add($(this)).addClass('is-active');
        $(this).nextAll(stars).removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $(stars).click(function(event) {
        $(".rating").removeClass("rating");
        $(this).addClass('rating');
        activeClassCount = $(this).index() + 1;
        $(this).prevAll(stars).addClass('is-active');
        if (input) {
            $(input).val(($(this).index() + 1)/2);
            console.log($(input).val(), activeClassCount)
        }
    });
}
```

Then you have to simply call this jQuery function when the DOM gets ready.

```
$(".c-rating").customStarRatings({
    childClass: ".c-rating__item",
    inputClass: ".rank"
});
```

**PS** The HTML markup is not confined to usage of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags only. All you need to do is call this custom function on the wrapper tag of ratings and input element.

*CSS edits:*

```
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px;
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(stars.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item: hover {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left: hover {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

The jQuery call to this function remains the same. Check the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bh22v6c3/1/).

Comment: thanks friend for the example, the example you have given me can not be used as follows: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8WEj.png) qualification between `0.5` `1` `1.5` `2` `2.5` `3` `3.5` `4` `4.5` and `5`

Comment: You can have the code run here or in https://jsfiddle.net because I can not make it work, nor does html code show me, I do not understand.

Comment: @AmLy Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bh22v6c3/1/ Have updated it in answer as well.

Comment: Great :) You can add the title of which expression expresses the qualification.

Comment: this can be added `title="Excellent - 5 stars"` or not?

Comment: @AmLy title attributes can be added in the HTML structure itself, no need to make this dynamic, as they work on hover properly. For example - add `title="Excellent - 5 stars"` attribute to `<li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>` tag

Comment: Thank you :) friend