# Multiple star ratings on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I've managed to get the following work with my Wordpress ACF.

[Link to stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637728/how-to-create-a-simple-star-rating-with-span-or-ul-li-using-css-and-jquery/46898776#46898776)

But there is still one issue I'm not able to resolve. We want to have multiple star ratings on our page, the rating is working ok, but the rating is put in a hidden field. But when we click on one star rating. All hidden fields will be updaten with the same value. And of course this ain't right ;-)

Below is the jQuery plugin code

```
(function ( $ ) { 

$.fn.customStarRatings = function(obj) {
    var wrapper = this;
    var stars = obj.childClass;
    var input = obj.inputClass;
    $(wrapper).hover(function() {
        activeClassCount = $(this).find('.rating').index() + 1;
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find(stars).slice(1, activeClassCount).addClass('is-active');
        $this.find(stars).slice(activeClassCount, 10).not('.rating').removeClass('is-active');
        //console.log($this.find(stars).slice(activeClassCount, 4).not('.rating'))
    });
    $(stars).hover(function() {
        $(this).prevAll(stars).add($(this)).addClass('is-active');
        $(this).nextAll(stars).removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $(stars).click(function(event) {
        $(".rating").removeClass("rating");
        $(this).addClass('rating');
        activeClassCount = $(this).index() + 1;
        $(this).prevAll(stars).addClass('is-active');
        if (input) {
            $(input).val(($(this).index() + 1));
            console.log($(input).val(), activeClassCount)
        }
    });
}

$(this).find(".acf-input").customStarRatings({
    childClass: ".c-rating__item",
    inputClass: ".rank"
});

}( jQuery ));
```

Below is the HTML of one star rating

```
<div class="acf-input">
    <ul class="c-rating">
        <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="1"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item  is-active" data-index="2"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item left is-active" data-index="3"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item  is-active" data-index="4"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item left is-active" data-index="5"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item  is-active" data-index="6"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item left is-active" data-index="7"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item is-active rating" data-index="8"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item left is-active" data-index="9"></li>
        <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="10"></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" class="rank" name="acf[field_59e75157e6ae9]" value="1">                    
</div>
```

I think it is in the section on the click. But I'm not that good jquery developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(input).val(($(this).index() + 1));
```

This line is globalizing the inputs. Change it to this:

```
$(this).parent().next(input).val(($(this).index() + 1));
```

Or the extended fix:

```
if ($(this).parent().next(input).length > 0) {
    $(this).parent().next(input).val(($(this).index() + 1));
    console.log($(this).next(input).val(), activeClassCount)
}
```

After the fiddle you've sent me, I realised that `this` refers to the star item, not the star container, and the input was next to the container. You need to first jump to the parent to reach the immediate `.rank` input. This way, your script will find the input and only update the input next to the stars.

Comment: After changing it, the input field isn't updated anymore :(

Comment: can you share a bit of DOM and what obj contains?

Comment: The update doesn't work either. I've updated my question with the DOM of one element